# Itunes connect autoingestion : Product type identifier "3"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Since 2 weeks now the autoingestion tool downloads CSV files with product type identifier "3".
I only have free Apps, so it used to be 1,7,1F,7F, but not 3.

I looked at the documentation on product type identifiers, and 3 is not referenced.

Does someone know what this mean ?

Comment: I've no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: You have the possibilty to download statistics in csv files automatically from a server thanks to the Autoingestion tool (https://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf page 8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a new Product code (3) that means re-downloads.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I have a question : are re-downloads (3) included in installs (1) ? To be clear, if I have 20 "1" and 10 "3", does it means 30 downloads or 20 ?

Comment: Re-downloads are apps that were deleted and then re-downloaded. I think re-downloads also includes installs on more than one registered device. I'm not sure about the latter, because the documentation does not implicitly include downloads on multiple devices under Product Identifier code 3.

Comment: I hate Apple when they release new export files without associated doc... And without warnings ! I decided to ignore stats with PI "3" since I think the "1" includes the "3".